# Using Python to validate numeric string in XML

Tags: python, xml

I have some hardware that creates a bazillion record XML file where the xml records look like this:

```
<Reading>
    <DeviceId>13553678</DeviceId>
    <Reading>1009735</Reading>
    <DataStatus>0</DataStatus>
</Reading>
```

Every once in awhile, we will experience hardware failure where a character value gets inserted into the Reading tag, like this:

```
<Reading>
    <DeviceId>13553678</DeviceId>
    <Reading>100F735</Reading>
    <DataStatus>0</DataStatus>
</Reading>
```

Unfortunately, the application that consumes this XML file will dump the ENTIRE file with a "Input string was not in a correct format" error.  I would like to write an intermediary program in Python to remove the bad records from the xml file, archive them, and then rebuild the file for processing. I have used python for simple text manipulation but I believe there are some XML features I could leverage.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the lxml module and the SAX parser [SAX](http://lxml.de/sax.html).

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by using the [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) module and [`XPath`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) expressions. Also see the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html) module on how to do proper logging.

- Configure a logger with a [`FileHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler)
- Get all inner `<Reading/>` nodes
- If their text doesn't consist only of digits, drop the parent node and log

```py
from lxml import etree
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('dropped_readings.log'))


tree = etree.parse(open('readings.xml'))

readings = tree.xpath('//Reading/Reading')
for reading in readings:
    reading_block = reading.getparent()
    value = reading.text

    if not all(c.isdigit() for c in value):
        reading_dump = etree.tostring(reading_block)
        logger.warn("Dropped reading '%s':" % value)
        logger.warn(reading_dump)
        reading_block.getparent().remove(reading_block)

print etree.tostring(tree, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

See the [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) builtin and [generator epxressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) for how the condition works.

Comment: Thanks.  This worked great on my home computer, but my co. firewall keeps blocking my import of the lxml module so need to figure out a way around that.

Comment: You probably mean *download*, not *import*, right? You should be able to download the lxml package [from PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.1) in advance, send it to you by e-mail or other means, and then do `pip install path-to/lxml.tar.gz`.